# Google Maps set zoom if only 1 marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a script that gets map markers from an object and then fits the markers to the bounds. This works fin except that when the object only contains 1 marker it zooms in way to far. Any suggestions on how I can set this so that if there is only on marker to set zoom to "x";

```
var results = [
      ['<!-- TMPL_VAR street_no --> <!-- TMPL_VAR street --> <!-- TMPL_VAR city -->, <!-- TMPL_VAR state --> <!-- TMPL_VAR zip -->',<!-- TMPL_VAR latitude -->,<!-- TMPL_VAR longitude -->]
  ];
var map;
function initMap() {
  bounds  = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
  });
  setMarkers(map);
}
function setMarkers(map) {
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
    result = results[i];
    position = new google.maps.LatLng(result[1], result[2]);
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: {lat: result[1], lng: result[2]},
      map: map,
      title: result[0]
    });
    bounds.extend(position)
  }
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
}
```

Comment: you can check marker length and use `map.setZoom(x)` to set zoom for map

Comment: tried if(marker.length = 1) { map.setZoom(14) } after setMarkers(map); and not working where should i do this?

Comment: if(marker.length == 1) `=` is assignment operator if still its doesn't work please make a working fiddle

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LyVgVL

Comment: In your case it would be if(results.length == 1) make sure you set the center of the map to single marker position

Comment: yea still not working...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `.fitBound` is preventing the bound you can try this by checking it with marker length and change code as

```
if(results.length == 1) {    
      map.setZoom(5);
      map.setCenter(position)
   }



if(results.length > 1){
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
  }
```

So now in case of one marker map center and zoom is set instead of bounds while in case of multiple marker bounds are used ignoring the zoom and center

See this [CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pPJxdj)